# Objective-C Change Sprite Sheet - Sparrow

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-sheet, sparrow-framework

I'm currently in the middle of developing an iOS universal app using the Sparrow framework and at the moment am trying to create a series of animations using Sprite Sheets. For the iPad Retina i have to output the frames of an animation at a high-res. Unfortunately for the animation to play properly i need to use multiple sprite sheets because of the iOS sprite sheet size limit.

On the simulator, simply switching out the sprite sheet works perfectly however on a real device this lowers the framerate and also can, if multiple animations are switching, give a memory warning and crash the app.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with Sparrow or with Cocoa? and how did you get around this issue?

If there isn't a fix for this performance issue, does anyone have any advice on how to deal with multiple sprite sheets on an iOS device?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently it's to do with the actual loading of the new sprite sheet. Sparrow version 1 doesn't support Asynchronous loading. However the guys at Sparrow have just released the BETA for version 2 and that does support Asynchronous loading so whilst it can't really help me (quite far down the development line) it would probably be better to use v2.

http://forum.sparrow-framework.org/topic/sparrow-20-beta